# Array required but Integer found

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to compare two values present in two different arrays but I end up getting the " Array required but Integer found " compile time error . I am really not able solve this. I have marked the line from where the error was coming. It would be very appreciable if anybody can help me out with this. Here is the code .

```
public class Banker
{

    int proccess, n, allocated[][], need[][], maximum[][], available[], safe[];
    boolean done[];

    public Banker(int n, int proccess) {
        this.n = n;
        this.proccess = proccess;
        allocated = new int[n][n];
        need = new int[n][n];
        maximum = new int[n][n];
        safe = new int[proccess];
        done = new boolean[proccess];
    }

    public void getSafeSequence() {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < proccess; ++i) {
            result = getLocation();
            if (result != -1) {
                safe[i] = result;
                done[result] = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println(" No Safe Sequence Exist ");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (result != -1)
            DisplaySequene();
    }

    public int getLocation() {
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < proccess; ++i) {
            if (done[i] != true) {
                flag = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                    ***if (available[i][j] < need[i][j])*** {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if (flag)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`available` is one dimensional array so you cannot write `available[i][j]`. Change it to smh like `available[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You defined `available[]` as a one dimensional array and use it with two dimensions `available[i][j]`.